# Как работает команда find_package() в cmake

Tags: cmake

Скажите, пожалуйста, как в `cmake` работает команда `find_package()`?

Мне не удалось найти исчерпывающего объяснения и понятных примеров, даже в официальной документации.

Например, если в проекте `cmake` вызывается команда `find_package()`, достаточно ли мне (на `Linux`) установить нужный пакет в систему? Или же мне нужно каким-то образом прицепить нужный пакет к проекту до вызова `find_package()`?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html

Comment: Достаточно, если пакет установлен в стандартные директории и поддерживает CMake. Перед вызовом можно указывать опции для конкретной библиотеки, если они нужны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не вдаваться в детали, то `find_package(Package)` просто ищет специальный cmake-файл, устанавливает несколько переменных и исполняет его аналогично `include`. Сей файл:

- В «классическом» `Module`-варианте называется именем вида `FindPackage.cmake`. Набор таких файлов распространяется вместе с самим `cmake` (на *nix системах обычно лежат где-то в `/usr/share/cmake/Modules`), а также может быть в дистрибутиве собираемого проекта (в типовом варианте для этого `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` присваивается каталог с оным).
- В `Config`-варианте такой файл называется `PackageConfig.cmake`, или `package-config.cmake` и ищется в одном из местоположений, описанных в документации.

Строго говоря, от самого файла не требуется делать что-то конкретное или устанавливать какие-либо переменные. Единственное — в случае если пакет «найден», то он должен установить `Package_FOUND` в истинное значение.

Все прочие действия и переменные остаются на усмотрение авторов конкретных модулей. За подробностями стоит обращаться к их документации или самим скриптам. Обычно устанавливаются:

- `Package_VERSION`
- `Package_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`
- `Package_LIBRARIES`

Обычно эти переменные являются *кешированными* (см. `CACHE`), так что по мере необходимости их можно переопределить из командной строки.

Подробности см. [в документации cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html).

> Например, если в проекте `cmake` вызывается команда `find_package()`, достаточно ли мне (на `Linux`) установить нужный пакет в систему? Или же мне нужно каким-то образом прицепить нужный пакет к проекту до вызова `find_package()`?

Обычно этого достаточно, подразумевая, что при этом также устанавливаются пакеты с заголовочными файлами и прочей мишурой для разработчиков (`*-dev` или `*-devel` пакеты).

Но т.к. всё это делается простым скриптом, то иногда он может не находить некоторые файлы т.к., например, они установлены в неожиданное для его автора место. В таких случаях обычно достаточно установить несколько входных и/или выходных переменных при запуске `cmake`, например, передав ему что-то вроде `-DPackage_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/package`. Но конкретные значение крайне зависят от конкретных же модулей. Зачастую, когда возникают подобные ошибки, приходится обращаться к коду самих скриптов поиска, чтобы понять, где же их надо погладить.