# Установка динамической библиотеки с помощью cmake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

У меня есть `C++/Qt` библиотека, которую я написал сам. Я понимаю, что для ее распространения, `cmake` должен устанавливать `.dll` (или `.so` для Linux) файлы и заголовочные файлы. Таким образом, я пишу следующий `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(my_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Network Sql REQUIRED)

set(HEADERS some_class.h)
set(SOURCES some_class.cpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Network Qt5::Sql)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ARCHIVE DESTINATION "lib"
                                RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin"
                                COMPONENT library)
install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION "include")
```

И получаю нужные файлы в директории `C:\Program Files (x86)\my_project`:

```
-- lib/libmy_project.dll.a
-- bin/libmy_project.dll
-- include/some_class.h
```

Однако, как только я пытаюсь слинковать свою библиотеку с тестовой программой:

```
find_package(my_project REQUIRED)
# ....
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} my_project)
```

То получаю ошибку еще на этапе генерации `Makefile`:

```
    By not providing "Findmy_project.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "my_project", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "my_project"
  with any of the following names:

    my_projectConfig.cmake
    my_project-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "my_project" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "my_project_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "my_project" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

То есть, он просто не понимает где ему искать. Как я понял, CMak'у необходим конфигурационный файл для моего проекта, и CMakeLists.txt для моей библиотеки должен каким-то образом его устанавливать. Однако информацию в интернете на этот счет я нашел очень обрывистую, без пояснений и толковых примеров (не там искал?). Все же, как и куда писать эти конфигурационные файлы для библиотек?

Comment: Связанный: [Как работает команда find_package() в cmake](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165953/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0-find-package-%d0%b2-cmake/1166069#1166069)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечного понимания я так и не приобрел, однако, я разобрался, что необходимо писать, чтобы правильно экспортировать библиотеку.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(some_project VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

# Инициализация параметров
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

# Поиск необходимых библиотек
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Network Sql REQUIRED)

# Файлы проекта
set(HEADERS some_class.h)
set(SOURCES some_class.cpp)

# Сборка библиотеки
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

# Линкуем необходимые библиотеки
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Network Qt5::Sql)

# Устанавливаем, какие заголовочные файлы должны поставляться вместе с библиотекой
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADERS}")

# Устанавливаем библиотеку
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}-config"
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}"
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
        PRIVATE_HEADER DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
        INCLUDES DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}")

install(EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}-config" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}")

export(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} FILE "${PROJECT_NAME}-exports.cmake")
```