# Как от CMake получить путь к include каталогу после find_package?

Tags: cmake

`<PackageName>_DIR` выводит путь к `<PackageName>Config.cmake`. 
`<PackageName>_ROOT` не выводит ничего. 
Каких-то других переменных я не нагуглил. 
К `Boost`, например, нашёл переменную `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS`, но она специфична для этой библиотеки. 
Существует ли нормальный способ добавить `<prefix>/<PackageName>*/include` в `target_include_directories` так, чтобы не зависеть от текущего расположения файлов, и вообще от платформы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменные, которые устанавливает `find_package()` ни как не нормируются (кроме `<Package>_FOUND`), так что, вообще говоря, одного гарантированного или хотя бы рекомендованного способа сделать это нет.

Большинство модулей для пути к хедерам, действительно, устанавливают переменную `<Package>_INCLUDE_DIRS`, некоторые — `<Package>_INCLUDE_DIR`, какие-то — `<Package>_INCLUDE_PATH`. Но что именно происходит в конкретном `Find`-модуле нужно смотреть в его документации ([`man cmake-modules`)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/manual/cmake-modules.7.html). Или если он самописный — в самом модуле (команда `find_package()` вызывает [обычный cmake-скрипт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165953/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0-find-package-%D0%B2-cmake/1166069#1166069)).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел интересный способ и заодно разобрался в свойствах `CMake`. Из таргетов (и не только) можно доставать свойства и задавать их. И даже, насколько понял, создавать новые свойства. Вот как можно этого добиться:

```
get_target_property(YourVariable YourTarget YOUR_PROPERTY)
```

В данном случае:

```
get_target_property(YourIncludeDirs YourTarget INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```